# Formatting datetime object in df.query(), Python

Tags: python, format

'I would like to format a datetime object within df.query(). The following command works for me

```
df.query(''''2001-01-01'<eventdate''')
```

where `eventdate` is a multi index column in `df`. However, I cannot get the following to work

```
m='2001-01-01'
df.query(f'''{m}<eventdate''')
```

which reads the error `invalid syntax`. I have tried the following with no luck.

```
ts=pd.Timestamp
m='2001-01-01'
df.query(f'''@ts({m})<eventdate''')
```

Any suggestions would be really appreeciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this but I got the error ```multi-line expressions are only valid in the context of data, use DataFrame.eval```

Comment: Thanks Berlin. This also has a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it with quotation marks around the date inside the query string, use this:

```
    m="'2001-01-01'"
    df.query('''{}<eventdate'''.format(m))
```